# Can a JFormattedTextField be assigned a formatter which has placeholders

Tags: java, formatter, jformattedtextfield

I've used the following line of code to only allow users to enter digits inside a JFormattedTextField which collects information on time

```
final JFormattedTextField periodTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
periodTextField.setFormatterFactory(new DefaultFormatterFactory(createFormatter("##:## - ##:##")));
```

When running my application the text field will appear as ": - :" by default, but I would like it to appear as "00:00 - 00:00" as default, and editing the text field will only change the values of the 0's nothing else. I've looked at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) guide for help on using formatters in java, but it doesn't mention how you can set default values. Is there a simple way to achieve what I need.

Comment: Have you tried `periodTextField.setValue(00000000)`?

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but when I delete a number, I want the number to revert back to 0. By setting the text, it looks good to begin with, but deleting a number in the text field will turn it into an empty string